# Allow the endpoint only if the user is authenticated

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to send a GET request with Angular to my Spring Boot application. To be authenticated, this is how I pass the token to the headers:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const token = getCookieValue('token');

    if (token) {
      const authRequest = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      return next.handle(authRequest);
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Browser gives me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/api/user-profile/get-data' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

This is my configuration in Spring Boot:

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy()));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/oauth").authenticated() // also tried with "/api/user-profile/**"
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

And this is how I can send a request and prevent a CORS error:

Sending a basic request (without token):

```js
this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + 'user-profile/get-data').subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

In Spring Boot, replaced `.requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**").permitAll()` with `.requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**", "/api/user-profile/**").permitAll()`.

Now I don't receive an error message but I can send a request without being authenticated and this is not my goal.

This is how I try to read the token:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final CustomUserService customUserService;
    private Jwt jwt;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String token = null;
        String username = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            // Check if token is valid
            try {
                jwt.isTokenValid(token, customUserService.loadUserByUsername(jwt.extractUsername(token)));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Response responseObj = Response.builder()
                        .code("UNAUTHORIZED")
                        .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .messages(Collections.singletonList("Invalid token"))
                        .build();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(responseObj);
                response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                response.getWriter().write(json);
                return;
            }
            username = jwt.extractUsername(token);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = customUserService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwt.isTokenValid(token, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but `authorizationHeader` is always `null`.

Comment: you can't use wild-cards when sending credentials... so be sure to specify methods and header names explicitly... you might also need to be https on both ends for that. A standard GET does not trigger pre-flight CORS check, or any CORS rules. Only the existence of a custom header (which your authorizationheader is) would trigger pre-flight. Also be aware that allowing script access to the cookie that contains your JWT could leave your clients vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue:

In Angular, I created the file **proxy.conf.json** in **src**.

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api/"
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

In **angular.json** I added the following into `"serve": {`

```json
"options": {
  "browserTarget": "angl:build",
  "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
},
```

In **package.json** I replaced `"start": "ng serve",` with `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json",`.

Problem solved, and it does exactly what I wanted.
Nothing changed in Spring Boot.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to write the following code to my .htaccess file to prevent CORS error:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, 
origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "authorization"
```

For changing or creating a .htaccess file you need access to the file system of your server.